# Cannot Resolve Symbol 'textView' in onBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm still learning to create a mobile app so i guess i make some small mistake here...

I'm trying to make a recyclerView, But there's an error in the Adapter.
i've been searching for the answer here, nothing worked for me. Here's my code

```
package com.abelherl.carttest;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private ArrayList<Item> items;

public ItemAdapter(ArrayList<Item> items){
    this.items = items;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View view;
    public final TextView textView8;
    public final TextView textView7;
    public final TextView textView10;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
        super(view);
        this.view = view;
        textView8 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        textView7 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        textView10 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View v = (View) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = items.get(position);

    holder.textView8.setText(item.getTextView8());
    holder.textView7.setText(item.getTextView7());
    holder.textView10.setText(item.getTextView10());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(items != null){
        return items.size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}


}
```

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: this code doesn't have or use a variable with that name. did you re-compile before running?

Comment: Are you sure you use the correct layout? (R.layout.item)

Comment: share your "item" layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `ItemAdapter` like this:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> { … }
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should extend ItemAdapter like this:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Itemadpater.ViewHolder>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change RecyclerView.Adapter to `RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add adapter name with holder name. I've made changes it will work.

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Item> items;

public ItemAdapter(ArrayList<Item> items){
    this.items = items;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View view;
    public final TextView textView8;
    public final TextView textView7;
    public final TextView textView10;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
        super(view);
        this.view = view;
        textView8 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        textView7 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        textView10 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View v = (View) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = items.get(position);

    holder.textView8.setText(item.getTextView8());
    holder.textView7.setText(item.getTextView7());
    holder.textView10.setText(item.getTextView10());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(items != null){
        return items.size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try now, i've made a change.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the ViewHolder provided by the function you override to your ViewHolder type and then use that.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = items.get(position);

    /* Cast first */
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;

    /* Then use */
    viewHolder.textView8.setText(item.getTextView8());
    viewHolder.textView7.setText(item.getTextView7());
    viewHolder.textView10.setText(item.getTextView10());
}
```

Your ViewHolder type is `ViewHolder` (you could change your class name to something more appropriate), whilst the function override provides the type you extend, which is `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.